# Chrome Extension: How to create context menu with custom name, instead of plugin name

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a basic chrome extension. After finding out that the [root context menu can only contain one item per plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7721649/1380710), I wanted to at least be able to name the parent something else than my plugin name:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Child Item 1",
    contexts:["selection"],
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Child Item 2",
    contexts:["selection"],
});
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hsObtyL.png]

So how do I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way I did it, was to create a parent item with a custom `title` and `id`, and then adding all the items I needed, as children to the parent item (to my `script.js` file):

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Custom Parent Name",
    contexts:["selection"],
    id: "parent",
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Child Item 1",
    contexts:["selection"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child1",
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Child Item 2",
    contexts:["selection"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child2",
});
```

Here's the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: While this, obviously, works, it seams that it would be more robust to wait for the parent's `chrome.contextMenus.create()` callback prior to creating the children.

Comment: @Makyen Perhaps a good point. I probably didn't realize the `create` method was asynchronous at the time. Feel free to add your own answer that takes this into account.